# how to project a epsg:4326 shapely geometry to epsg:3857?

Tags: python, projection, shapely

I'm working with a geodataset of fields. I want to compute the surface of each parcel on the fly when they are displayed on the map (the rational for that is not relevant here).

When I was able to manipulate the dataset, I would have simply do the following:

```py
# I know 3857 is not optimal everywhere but that will do for the example
gdf["surface"] = gdf.to_crs(3857).area
```

Now what I have is the following:

```py
feat = gdf[gdf.id == change["new"]].squeeze()
# this is a shaely geometry in 4326 and before computing area,
# I would need to reproject it
surface = feat.geometry
```